# Advertising multiple independent BLE Services using CBPeripheralManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

I have two methods, each which adds a service to the peripheral manager. When I get the `didAddService` callback I use the `[manager startAdvertisingServices:]` method with the services that have been added (so the array used as the value for the `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey` key has either 1 or 2 service UUIDs in it.)

When I add the second service and try to advertise them both, I always get the error `Advertising has already started.`

I've tried to use `[manager stopAdvertising]` and then adding the new services, but the stopAdvertising method is asynchronous, so sometimes it still fails (it hasn't stopped advertising by the time I call `startAdvertisingServices` again.)

I have no problem advertising/reading/writing them individually, and if I wait after calling stopAdvertising I can start advertising them together, but that seems like a hack.

The way I can think of to do this safely is to KVO on the `isAdvertising` property of the peripheral manager and hold flags for whether or not each service should be advertising, so that I know exactly when the advertising stops and I can safely start again. I'm also not sure if this will have an affect on Centrals in the field if I start and stop advertising just to add new services.

What's the proper way to advertise multiple services using the peripheral manager?

Comment: What's that `startAdvertisingServices:` method? I can't find anything about it

Comment: Sorry that must have been a method I wrote to advertise multiple services with the PeripheralManager. To solve this problem I kept a state machine tracking which services had been added to the manager, and when they had all been added I started advertising.